# How to enable/disable multiple submit buttons on a form depending on selection of a radio button

Tags: javascript, python, html, cgi

I have a form that lists all the milestones in a project.
The form has two submit buttons. One displays the tasks in the milestone. The other submit button is supposed to execute a script to generate a burndown chart for the selected button.
Here is what I want to do

1. When the page loads and no milestone is selected, both the submit
   buttons are disabled — This is achieved.
2. When the user selects any milestone, both the submit buttons get
   activated - I need help with this. I know how to link enable/disable
   of one submit button with a radio selection. It is the two submit
   buttons I have issues with.
3. Depending on which button is pressed, appropriate Python script
   should execute in the background. — I will work on this once my
   disable buttons issue is done.

At present, when the page loads, both the submit buttons are in disabled state. And even after  I select a milestone, none of them gets enabled. I suspect, it may be because it may be returning an array of submit buttons and may be I need to have logic for the same? Any help is appreciated. Here is the code.

```
<form action="show_milestone.py" method="POST" name="milestone_form">
<table><tbody><tr>
    <td>Milestone ID</td>
    <td>Milestone Name</td>
    <td>Milestone Start Date</td>
    <td>Milestone End Date</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="milestone_id" value="1" onclick="javascript:document.milestone_form.submit.disabled=false"> 1<br></td>
    <td>milestone_1</td>
    <td>03/24/2012</td>
    <td>04/07/2012</td>
</tr></tbody></table>
<p></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Show Tasks" disabled="">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Burndown Chart" disabled="">
</form>
```

Comment: you mis-formatted the code a little there.  Have you seen knockout.js?  It's an awesome library that would be a little overkill if you were using it just for this, but it would make this problem trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle that does what you say you need:

http://jsfiddle.net/bDwxB/1/

And here's the jQuery and HTML you'd need:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=buttonGroup]').change(function(){
        $('input.buttonGroupDependent').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#' + $(this).data().trigger).attr('disabled', false);
    });
});​
</script>

<input type="radio" name="buttonGroup" data-trigger="button1" />
<input type="radio" name="buttonGroup" data-trigger="button2" />
<input type="radio" name="buttonGroup" data-trigger="button3" />

<form action="/echo/json/1">
    <input type="submit" id="button1" value="Button 1" class="buttonGroupDependent" disabled/>
</form>
<form action="/echo/json/2">
    <input type="submit" id="button2" value="Button 2" class="buttonGroupDependent" disabled/>
</form>
<form action="/echo/json/3">
    <input type="submit" id="button3" value="Button 3" class="buttonGroupDependent" disabled/>
</form>​
```

Comment: Thanks Milimetric, my problem is little different. I have only one radio button to select a milestone. When the user click the radio button, two submit buttons should be enabled. Now in later stage, depending on which submit button the user clicks, appropriate script will be run.

Comment: That just seems like a simpler scenario than what I've set up above.  You should go to the fiddle link and play with it until you've got what you need.  I wasn't intending to solve your exact problem, just showing you how to use jQuery, classes, names, data- attributes, and ids to interact with html elements.  Study the code and you'll find everything you need to solve your problem is there.