# How to disable multiple submit buttons with each one belonging to a different form when the text inputs are empty?

Tags: jquery

I have already searched a solution for my question and I found this one:
[(the solution on jsfiddle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954910/how-to-enable-disable-multiple-submit-buttons-on-a-form-depending-on-selection-o?answertab=active#tab-top).However, I have 3 different text inputs instead of radio buttons and I don't know how to do it. Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance.

**HTML CODE**

```
<form action="/echo/json/1">
    <input type="submit" id="button1" value="Button 1" class="buttonGroupDependent" disabled/>
</form>
<form action="/echo/json/2">
    <input type="submit" id="button2" value="Button 2" class="buttonGroupDependent" disabled/>
</form>
<form action="/echo/json/3">
    <input type="submit" id="button3" value="Button 3" class="buttonGroupDependent" disabled/>
</form>
```

**JS CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=buttonGroup]').change(function(){
        $('input.buttonGroupDependent').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#' + $(this).data().trigger).attr('disabled', false);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `onchange` (EDIT: see bottom of post) event to respond to the textbox values changing. Have the submit buttons default to being disabled.

Something like this:

```
<form>
     <input type="text" id="text1" />
     <input type="submit" id="button1" />
</form>
<form>
     <input type="text" id="text2" />
     <input type="submit" id="button2" />
</form>    <form>
     <input type="text" id="text3" />
     <input type="submit" id="button3" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$("#text1").on('keyup', function() {
    if($(this).val() === '') {
        $("#button1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    } else {
        $("#button1").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
// repeat for other two
```

If you want to be really fancy, you could use a class and some id parsing like so:

```
$(".required").on('keyup', function() {
    if($(this).val() === '') {
        $("#button" + $(this).attr('id').substr(-1)).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    } else {
        $("#button" + $(this).attr('id').substr(-1)).removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

EDIT: `change` seems to only be firing upon leaving the text box; haven't used this event before, maybe that's typical. jsFiddle with working version of mine: http://jsfiddle.net/64DC3/2/

EDIT: Added by request of the OP: The HTML for the second JS method.

```
<form action="/echo/json/1">
    <input type="text" class="required" id="text1" />
    <input type="submit" id="button1" value="Button 1" disabled/>
</form>
<form action="/echo/json/2">
    <input type="text" class="required" id="text2" />
    <input type="submit" id="button2" value="Button 2" disabled/>
</form>
<form action="/echo/json/3">
    <input type="text" class="required" id="text3" />
    <input type="submit" id="button3" value="Button 3" disabled/>
</form>
```

Comment: Hello David, I appreciate your answer. Could you edit the html code according to the 2nd solution that you have suggested? (I see it the fiddle, thank you)

Comment: The html in the fiddle has it, but I'll add it to my post as well.

Answer (score 0):

modifying the fiddle on the article you referenced to apply to text inputs: http://jsfiddle.net/dzWHe/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=buttonGroup]').focus(function(){
        $('input.buttonGroupDependent').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#' + $(this).data().trigger).attr('disabled', false);
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry Dom Day but in the fiddle that you modified, when I click on a text box to write something in it, the submit button of the clicked text box becomes enabled. However, I want it to stay disabled until I write something in the text box.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='text']").on('change', function(){
        if(this.value.length) $(this).closest('form').find('.buttonGroupDependent').attr('disabled', false);
        else $(this).closest('form').find('.buttonGroupDependent').attr('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/dzWHe/6/)